# Adding Columns to Pandas DataFrame from Class

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I'm looking to improve my OOP skillset and have wrote a script to pull stock data and run some simple statistics. I am able to run and call each function within the Evaluation class individually (commented below), but run into issues when trying to loop through a list of tickers and append the statistics to the initial dataframe.

```
import datetime as d
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np

start = d.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = d.datetime(2020, 4, 17)

class Security(object):
    def _init__(self, ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.data_platform = data_platform
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date

    def fetch_stock_data(self, ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date):
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date)
        return df


class Evaluation(Security):

    def __init__(self, ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date):
        self.df = Security.fetch_stock_data(
            self, ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date)

    def simple_moving_average(self, period):
        df = self.df
        df['SMA-{}'.format(period)] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(period).mean()
        return df['SMA-{}'.format(period)]

    def exp_moving_average(self, period):
        df = self.df
        df['EMA_{}'.format(period)] = df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=period).mean()
        return df['EMA_{}'.format(period)]

    def rsi(self, period):
        df = self.df
        delta = df['Adj Close'].diff()

        up = delta * 0
        down = up.copy()

        up[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
        down[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]

        up[up.index[period - 1]] = np.mean(up[:period])
        up = up.drop(up.index[:(period - 1)])

        down[down.index[period - 1]] = np.mean(down[:period])
        down = down.drop(down.index[:(period - 1)])

        rs = up.ewm(span=period - 1).mean() / down.ewm(span=period - 1).mean()

        rsi_calc = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
        df['rsi'] = rsi_calc
        return df['rsi']


# pypl = Evaluation('PYPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
# print(csgs.df)
# print(csgs.simple_moving_average(50))
# print(csgs.exp_moving_average(26))
# print(csgs.rsi(14))


tickers = ['PYPL', 'TSLA']

for i in tickers:
    df = Evaluation(i, 'yahoo', start, end)
    df['SMA'] = df.simple_moving_average(50)
    df['EMA'] = df.exp_moving_average(26)
    df['rsi'] = df.rsi(14)
    print(df)
```

I'm receiving a TypeError, which I believe to be related to referencing the Evaluation class.

```
TypeError: 'Evaluation' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Evaluation returns an object that stores a `df ` attribute not a `df`

Comment: So you should do `eval = Evaluation(i, 'yahoo', start, end)` then `eval.df['foo'] = data`

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing object methods with dataframe methods. In your example, `df` is an `Evaluation` object, not a dataframe.

```
>>>e = Evaluation()                                                                                                  
>>>type(e)                                                                                                  
__main__.Evaluation

>>>type(e.df)                                                                                         
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The line `df['SMA'] = df.simple_moving_average(50)` fails because you can't add a column to an object. You need to use `df.df['SMA'] = df.simple_moving_average(50)`.

As NomadMonad pointed out, it is confusing to use df as the variable name for an Evaluation object, so it would be better to give it a different name. However, `eval` is a built-in function in python, so it would be better to use `e`.

Also, you should change the class designs for several reasons

- In python 3 there is no need to inherit from `Object`
- The `__init__` method of `Security` has only one leading underscore instead of two.
- You don't want `Evaluation` to inherit from `Security`. Instead, pass a `Security` object in the `__init__` method of `Evaluation`.
- You don't want to call a method that scrapes a website when you instantiate an object. The call to pandas_datareader should be a separate method.
- You don't need to pass parameters to methods if those values are set in the `__init__` method. You can access them with `self`.
- You don't need modify the underlying dataframe in your Evaluation methods. Instead return the value produced by the method.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web 


class Security:
    def _init__(self, ticker, data_platform, start_date, end_date):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.data_platform = data_platform
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.df = None

    def fetch_stock_data(self):
        self.df = web.DataReader(self.ticker, self.data_platform, self.start_date, self.end_date)


class Evaluation:

    def __init__(self, security):
        self.security = security

    def simple_moving_average(self, period):
        df = self.security.df
        return df['Adj Close'].rolling(period).mean()

    def exp_moving_average(self, period):
        df = self.security.df
        return df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=period).mean()

    def rsi(self, period):
        df = self.security.df
        delta = df['Adj Close'].diff()
        up = delta * 0
        down = up.copy()
        up[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
        down[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
        up[up.index[period - 1]] = np.mean(up[:period])
        up = up.drop(up.index[:(period - 1)])
        down[down.index[period - 1]] = np.mean(down[:period])
        down = down.drop(down.index[:(period - 1)])
        rs = up.ewm(span=period - 1).mean() / down.ewm(span=period - 1).mean()
        return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)


start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17)

s = Security(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
e = Evaluation(security=s)
```

Comment: Eric... How can you filter with securities data frame above.